# rewrite rule not working on https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

On apache, I have this rewrite rule under http

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)\.html$ mypage.php?val1=$1&val2=$2 [L,R=301]
```

and after, this rewrite rule that move all http page on https

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The rule works correctly alone but not together

EDIT

I get error 404

Comment: What error do you get when the rules are used together?

Comment: I get error 404

Comment: What url is causing the error?

Comment: all url. If I remove the rule about https, the first rewrite url works correctly.
Adding the second rule, I have error 404

Comment: did you installed https correctly?when you test the site.com alone with https ,is it working fine?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you missed the [QSA flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) to pass the existing query string to `https` url:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=301]
```